# How to build clang-llvm on windows using source code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, clang, ninja

Hi I am working on Static Analysis using clang in Windows,I have referred the following link "http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html",

I am using developer command prompt to build Clang and LLVM from the source code using Ninja.

Everything works fine upto cmake command, but when I give command "ninja", 
files start to build and after building few files the command fails, 
exception being displayed is not constant, 
every time I run I get a new exception.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYXWg.png)

Its taking considerably a large amount of time and space to build.
Is this procedure correct? kindly let me know if there is any other way to build clang-llvm?

I have followed every step mentioned in the link.
Below are the software's I have installed :

a)Visual Studio 2017 community edition

b)llvm source code,

c)cmake

d)ninja

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add some specific examples of the exceptions/errors you are getting when you build. This will help us help you!

Comment: The exception i got was: ```Unable to open Config.exe for writting``` .

Comment: The linked page lists *many commands* for different purposes. Please, specify (in the question post) the ones which you **actually** use. Also, please add **exact error message** to the **question post**. "Exact" means copying the message literally from the build log, including call trace (if it has), line numbers and so on.

Comment: The commands used are ```cmake -G Ninja ../llvm -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=ON```  and 
```ninja```

Comment: As of now i dont have the exact error message, as i have not taken screenshot of the message. To reproduce the exception it will take lot of time

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the exception i got when i executed the ```ninja```` command.